# How to set task's exit code to non-zero value when batch job fails?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-task

I want to set exit code of task_execution table to non zero value when my batch job fails. As per [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#batch-failures-and-tasks), I have set the value of property `spring.cloud.task.batch.failOnJobFailure` to true, and it is setting the value of task_execution's exit_code to 1 but it is triggering the batch Job again. Is there any way through which I can stop triggering batch job again ?

Basically, It is running both command line runners(the one which is written in my batch application, and the other provided by spring i.e. TaskJobLauncherCommandLineRunner. I want to run only my commanLineRunner.

Comment: What version of Spring Cloud Task are you using.  That feels like it was an issue we fixed...

Comment: @MichaelMinella I was using 2.0.0.Release version, after your comment I tried with latest version and it worked for me. Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in earlier version of spring cloud task batch(I was using 2.0.0.release), this is resolved in the later versions. Updating dependency version solved my problem.